# Not able to add Group to an User from save_model but able to do from Terminal

Tags: django, django-models, save, django-admin

I am using save_model to add an User to particular Group

```
def UserAdmin(UserAdmin):

   def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
       adminOb = Group.objects.get(name='Administrator')
       adminOb.user_set.add(obj.pk)
       adminOb.save()
       obj.save()
```

This code is not adding the `obj.pk` to `adminOb' the  but when I do this in terminal I am able to save

In terminal I did this

```
   adminOb = Group.objects.get(name='Administrator')
   adminOb.user_set.add(44)
   adminOb.save()
```

Note : I use werkzeug debugging tool, via which I can console in browser, I tested in this console, for the console to appear in the browser the page should have some error, so instead of `adminOb.save()` I used `adminOb.saved()` ,then in console I run this `adminOb.save()`, Surprisingly this is saving the adminOb

Comment: call `obj.save()` before `adminOb.save()` Also, ` adminOb.user_set.add(obj)` should be enough

Comment: And before `adminOb.user_set.add(obj.pk)`.  `obj.pk` is `None` until you first save the object.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper  i did that, still I m not able to save, here is my admin.py  http://pastebin.com/nUNDXfUj

Comment: @karthikr, i did that, still I m not able to save, here is my admin.py pastebin.com/nUNDXfUj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake I done is I didn't exclude the groups, which made to override Group of an user with the form fields,

```
fieldsets = (
(None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
(_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
(_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser'
                               )}),
(_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
)
```

Comment: Lol, have done the same and couldn't figure out what's happening! Simple problems are the worst to identify :P

Answer (score 0):

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.save() 
    adminOb = Group.objects.get(name='INDURE USER')
    adminOb.user_set.add(obj.pk)
    adminOb.save()
```

Try this because in many to many fields it cannot set a field value until it gets the id of another field. Until the user is not created, it cannot set its group, so first we need to save the object then add modifications or updates. Thus it saves once the object is created in case of many to many fields. Thus this is a transaction problem for many to many fields in Django.
And dont forget to exclude groups in "fields".